# 'Out of memory' error in Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I know this is quite a common problem, but all the solutions I have tried have failed.

Basically I want to train a big neural network and I obtain 'Out of memory' error.

My training set is a `729 x 3456` matrix of doubles and the neural network is a so called 'autoencoder' with layers of these sizes

```
3456 - 4000 - 2000 - 1000 - 300 - 1000 - 2000 - 4000 - 3456
```

In my code, first of all I do

```
net = feedforwardnet([layer1, layer2, layer3, layer4, layer3, layer2, layer1], 'trainscg');
net = configure(net, Dtrain', Dtrain');
```

where I use the 'trainscg' function because I read that it is the one that uses less memory.
Then I initialize the weights and biases according to some values (which I have already calculated), set the 'transferFcn' and start training.

I tried cleaning the workspace as much as possible and I also tried to put

```
net.efficiency.memoryReduction = 4;
```

before training, since I read it can help. Anyway I still have 'Out of memory', even if I increase the value to 60.

Here is the output of the command 'memory', executed when the workspace contains just the training set and four numbers (the size of the layers)

```
>> memory
Maximum possible array:      4508 MB (4.727e+09 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:      4508 MB (4.727e+09 bytes) *
Memory used by MATLAB:      1927 MB (2.020e+09 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):      8080 MB (8.472e+09 bytes)

*  Limited by System Memory (physical + swap file) available.
```

What else can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: Not an expert in Matlab but shouldn’t `configure(net, Dtrain', Dtrain')` be `configure(net, Dtrain, 'Dtrain')`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but don't think so. `Dtrain` is my training set, which is composed in row-major fashion. So I just transpose it since Matlab uses column-major. The second and third arguments of that function are just the input and the desired output and, since this net is an autoencoder, they have to coincide.

Comment: @Xufox no the ' operator is the transpose operator

Comment: @minomic What OS and architecture (32/64 bit) are you running Matlab on?

Comment: Have you identified what row causes the error, by breakpoints or selectively commenting out? With only two lines of code it is difficult to tell what causes the problem. Does it work when passing smaller arrays of arrays? For an uninitiated, how do the layers relate to the training set?

Comment: According to this (http://se.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/feedforwardnet.html) example, Dtrain' is not Dtrain':

[x,t] = simplefit_dataset;
net = feedforwardnet(10);
net = train(net,x,t);

Comment: I'm running Matlab on a Windows 7 64 bit OS.
The code I'm using is OK, since it works with smaller arrays. The problem here is the dataset which is too large. In fact I tried to split it in several parts with the `memoryReduction` option, but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: AFAIK. I have just started reading about MATLAB's NN and I have also big data. I am thinking of the way how to save a huge matrix in a disk and read sections of it from it.
I've come across something called __Incremental Training__. My understanding is you can train NN to particular state, save the state, re-use to further train NN. I will be testing it. Let me know if that can be helpful. I'm looking forward to your opinion :)

Comment: Maybe (and I'm saying maybe!) I managed to solve the problem by increasing the size of the swap file. Now if I tipe `memory` I see that I have some 20 GB of free memory. I don't know if this is THE solution, but I didn't experience the problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the data type of your data and the memory used by that data type. Try using the one with minimum memory requirement. For eg: double takes 8 bytes and single takes 4 bytes for same number. You can use **whos** command to check the memory usage.[image: checking memory size of data in Matlab]

Also, you can check the performance of your system  from task manager as shown in image below before running the code. May be some other process on your system is taking most of the memory and can be stopped.[image: checking memory and CPU usage]